# How to convert a FLAC file to WAV file using java?

Tags: java, wav, encoder, decoder, flac

I want to convert a given flac file to a wav file. Most of the questions on StackOverflow are the opposite of my question. Have anyone an idea how to solve this problem ? I heard something about JavaFlacEncoder [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaflacencoder/) but I could not find a method to convert flac to wave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flac -d` to (from the `man` page)

> ```
> Decode (the default behavior is to encode)
> ```

Another option would be the [JustFLAC](https://github.com/drogatkin/JustFLAC) library, again you need to *decode* from FLAC. WAV is uncompressed audio.

Comment: I give it a try Thanks :) And Thanks for the explanation. :)

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch is there a possibility to set the Sample Rate of a given Flac file using the JustFlac library ? I need to convert a given FLAC file with more than 8000Hz Sample Rate to 8000HZ Sample Rate,.. thanks

Comment: Probably not. Resampling audio != decompressing audio. Flac is audio compression. You can probably do it with the java sound API.

Comment: Thx I've tried it with the Java Sound API but, for FLAC files I get an UnsupportedAudioFileException("file is not a supported file type"). I think there is no provider within the API for FLAC files. So I tried an ugly workaround. First I decompressed the audio to a wav file then re-sampled the wav file to 8kHz and compressed to a flac file again. Until there is no other way or a better solution I use this for my purpose. Anyways thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the official FLAC code library. Of course, its API is not for Java but C/C++, but you can write a class using JNI that uses a tiny bit of C code to act as a bridge between the Java and native environments. [Here's a description for how to do that for FLAC decoding](https://klipspringer.avadeaux.net/decoding-the-flac-audio-format-in-java/), and [here's a simple demo program](https://klipspringer.avadeaux.net/files/examples/FlacDecodeFile.java.html) that converts a FLAC to a WAV using the [FLAC decoding library](https://klipspringer.avadeaux.net/guide/flac-decoding/) described there.